# Compare two tables in Hive without apply JOINS

Tags: hadoop

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB. Both having same set of columns C1, C2. Now need to compare both the table are having same DATA or NOT. How do you do without use JOIN. I tried MINUS operator ie., 
SELECT * FROM TableA
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TableB
But this is not supported in HIVE. May be impala has this SET operator?

Please suggest how to do without JOINS. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can try IN/NOT IN , EXISTS functions in Hive. Please have a look at this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE T1.X = T2.Y)

WHERE T1.X = T2.Y are the "key"

Answer (score 0):

```
create table student
(
id integer,
subject string,
total_score integer
);

  insert into student
   (id, subject, total_score)
 values
   (1, 'math', 90);
insert into student
   (id, subject, total_score)
 values
   (1, 'science', 100);
insert into student
   (id, subject, total_score)
 values
   (2, 'math', 90);
insert into student
   (id, subject, total_score)
 values
   (2, 'science', 80);

---------- MINUS ---------

 select id,subject, 
                total_score
  from (  select max (id) id,
                subject, 
                total_score,
                 count (*)
            from ( 
            select  *
                      from student
                     where     id = 1
                  union all
                    select  *
                      from student
                     where     id = 2
                  ) merged_data
        group by subject, total_score
          having count (*) = 1
       ) minus_data
 where id is not null;

id  subject total_score
2   science 80
1   science 100
```